# Send email using Telnet

Tags: email, telnet

I found this article which explains sending email from telnet
http://www.kongtechnology.com/2008/01/27/smtp-authentication-and-send-emails-using-telnet/

but actually I have problem with it.

when i wrote this command

```
auth login
```

I got

```
Connection to host lost.
```

so, what is the problem?

Comment: You need to read the SMTP spec first so you understand how it works.. e.g. you should greet the server with `HELO` or `EHLO`

Comment: did you check that your smtp port 25 is opened and its not blocked on firewall and aslo you have started your virtual smtp throgh iss

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ionfish.org/mxlookup

Type the URL of the site you want to find's mail server.

Open CMD, type:

```
telnet mx.sitedomain.com 25
```

then

```
HELO mx.sitedomain.com
```

next

```
MAIL FROM: president@whitehouse.gov
```

then

```
RCPT TO: secretary@whitehouse.gov
```

finally

```
SUBJECT: This message was brought to you in part by the moon.
```

Note: You need to send authentication requests, because most mail servers do not allow anonymous *unsolicited* mail to be sent. (spam).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

Comment: I'm using `telnet` to send emails. The emails are going straight to the `spam` folder. How can I prevent this?